# Static library containes undefined reference from other headers #define

Tags: static-libraries, msp430

I am building an msp430 static library. When I am linking against it I get  messages Undefined reference to functions. If I check it with nm they are referenced with T, how ever it containe #define of constans referenced with U.
The library build with -rcs options.

Comment: But what is your question ?

Comment: I think that your are using a C++ or C compiler and that the build is done on a Windows PC ? Is that exact ? Can you precise your context : Windows ? C or C++ or other ?

Comment: `#define`d constants should not show up in any object file. Your (secret) code apparently did not use the header correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The linking problem solved, it was wrong sequence of the options in the Makefile and the #define-d constans resolved in compile time however it is shown U -ndefined.